# Objects in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a piece of text and every time you click on it the text changes to the next item in the object. I also need the name of the one saying the text so I used a multidimensional array like this:

```
let texts = {
  0:{
    "name" : "Bob",
    "text" : "Hello, this is a text",
  },
  1:{
    "name" : "Peter",
    "text" : "Hey there.",
  },
};
```

This is my state:

```
this.state = {
  textNumber: 0,
};
```

And this is the function I call onPress:

```
nextScene = () => {
      if(this.state.textNumber >= Object.keys(texts).length-1){

      }
      else{
        this.setState({textNumber: this.state.textNumber+1})
      }
    };
```

It works perfectly just the way I want it. But my question is: is this the way it should be done in React Native? Or is there a better way?

Comment: You're using a local state to keep the current number, which is fine, until you want to access it from other component of the App. You may need [redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) to persist them in a global state.

Comment: What you have there isn't array at all but a multidimensional object.  This is worth noting in case you are expecting array-like behaviours and methods to exist on it (like push, map, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want an array of objects:

```
let texts = [
  {
    "name" : "Bob",
    "text" : "Hello, this is a text",
  },
  {
    "name" : "Peter",
    "text" : "Hey there.",
  },
];
```

Then you can do:

```
if(this.state.textNumber < this.state.texts.length-1) {
  this.setState({textNumber: this.state.textNumber+1});
}
```

If you want a loop, you can also do the following:

```
this.setState({textNumber: this.state.textNumber+1 % this.state.texts.length});
```

About your question, there is no difference between doing this in React Native or not. This is merely JS.

It is fine to keep this in the state (both React or RN). If you want more fancy solution you can write a `HOC` to manage the state of your component (see for example [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose)).

Answer (score -1):

```
const DATA = [
  {
    'title': 'Test Series (12,13)',price:"1000",
  }, 
];
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).